# i cannot use geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById?

Tags: c#, xcode, html, webbrowser-control, picturebox

```
namespace WebCap
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Skybound.Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize(@"C:\Program Files\xulrunner");
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate(addtxbox.Text);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void geckoWebBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, Skybound.Gecko.GeckoNavigatingEventArgs e)
        {
            addtxbox.Text = geckoWebBrowser1.Url.ToString();
        }

        private void geckoWebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((geckoWebBrowser1.Url.ToString() == "http://kolotibablo.com/bablo.php?action=workInterface"))
            {
                HtmlElement elem = geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mainCaptchaImg");
                string src = elem.GetAttribute("src");
                this.ptcapget.ImageLocation = src;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i use Skybound GeckoFX to make webbrowser in C#, but i can't use

```
HtmlElement elem = geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mainCaptchaImg")
```

It show this error Error:

'Cannot implicitly convert type 'Skybound.Gecko.GeckoElement' to 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement'

Answer (score 1):

The `GetElementById` method returns a `GeckoElement`,  *not* a  `HtmlElement`.

Much like you cannot store a `string` as an `int`, you cannot store a `GeckoElement` as an `HtmlElement` which is what you are trying to do here.

Amend your local variable type and all should be well:

```
GeckoElement elem = geckoWebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("mainCaptchaImg")
```